# Unable to find the xpath using IE 11

Tags: python, selenium

I have selenium Python code where I need to login to a portal using IE11.

So I developed the code in a windows server which had IE 11 and was able to fetch the results. But now I need to move this code to another windows server but the same code I see that IE is opening but is not continuing further. It is not able to find the user name xpath itself.

**Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='usrname']**

It will be helpful if anyone would suggest on this as it is working in one server and not in the other with the same IE 11 version. Any changes need to be done to the IE settings ?

Comment: you need to set all security zones in the browser the same level.

Comment: Tried keeping medium and medium-high security for all the zones but still the same.

Comment: see this page for various requirements: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration